# How to loop through this specifig relation model in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a table called "Relations" that looks as follows:

`Relations (PersonId1, PersonId2, RelationTypeId)`

The primary key is `(PersonId1, PersonId2, RelationTypeId)`

There are two other tables, referencing to the foreign keys but that does not really matter here.

So a relation is defined for example `(Mary, Andre, 3)` where 3 would be referenced to an other table and would mean for example ("a friend").

My requirement is to see all friends of a specifig person but also the friends of the persons friends, so not only the first layer but also the second.

For example this would be the relation table

```
Andre   Mary    3
Mary    Carl    3
Chris   James   3 (irrelevent in our case)
```

So i want a query where I have the PersonId of Andre and the RelationTypeId. The result should be this:

```
Andre   Mary    3
Mary    Carl    3
```

In my understanding it is not possible to build a query that would give this result, but i am not sure, that is why i want to know it.

Hope you understand my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: I would fetch all the friends of the first person in a subquery and then run `in` clause against them in outer query.

Comment: Why is `RelationTypeId` a primary key?

Comment: @Tony DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: @Jainik could you maybe write a small query how it would look like?

Comment: @JCode because the combination of 2 persons and a relation type is always unique

Comment: Sure, I just added a simple query in answer below

Answer (score 0):

Below query will return the list of friends of person1 and their friends.

```
select 
   distinct personId2
from 
   relations 
where 
   personId1 in (select distinct personId2 from relations where personId1 = <person_name>) 
or personId1 = <person_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a recursive CTE (common table expression). It’ll process query results multiple times because the main SELECT query calls the CTE part recursively. CTE is a part of a SELECT query (starts with WITH). This code will return the data subsets you’re looking for.

I use it to boost data access efficiency, when I need to, e.g., select, paginate, or display page rows linked with a specific page, etc. It’s works in actual for MySQL 8.